# Linux Grant Android Studio (AVD) permissions /dev/kvm (Permissions Denied)

Tags: android, linux, permissions, kvm

I'm confused with how to give permissions to Android Studio to install Virtual Devices through AVD manager.

I tired to add permissions to the folder and relogged-in without success. I'm also confused with commands regarding group and username; am I suppose to substitute username with name of user.

Currently if I do theses commands I get

```
ls -al /dev/kvm
crw-rw---- 1 root root 10, 232 May  7 20:23 /dev/kvm

grep kvm /etc/group
I get nothing printed
```

So, I know there is no group. I don't want to give privilages to root just the user name for example "blade".

I also checked with the device supports KVM

```
egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
8
kvm-ok 
8
```

Thanks!

Comment: What Linux distribution is it?

Comment: It is Parrot OS 3.11. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

First, you'll need to install the `qemu-kvm` package. For Debian/Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install qemu-kvm
```

Next, add your user to the `kvm` group:

```
sudo adduser <username_here> kvm
```

Finally, log out and log back in or reboot your computer for the changes to take effect.

See complete tutorial at https://www.linuxslaves.com/2018/10/fix-android-studio-devkvm-device-permission-denied-ubuntu.html

Comment: These instructions worked perfectly on Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon

Answer (score 0):

Update VT from Bios Setting

1. Power on the system and press[delete] key to enter BIOS [EZ Mode]
2. Press [F7] key to enter BIOS [Advance Mode] as below picture：
   (If press [delete] key to enter [Advanced Mode] directly and then no need to press [F7] key any more)
3. Select  [Advanced] page and click [CPU Configuration] item
4. Select [Intel(VMX) Virtualization Technology] item and set to [Enabled]
5. Press [F10] key and click [OK] ,the system will auto reboot
   [image]